# jquery ajax form validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form where I first do a validation, then submit it via ajax, where some of the fields are checked, such as a user name, which might already exist in the database. I want to display either of these error conditions right after the element in question.  The form elements look like this:

```
  <span class="inputRow">
    <span class="formLabel">
        <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
    </span>
    <span class="formInput">
        <input id="user_name" name="user_name" class="inputText required" title="User Name" tabindex="3" type="text" value="<?= $user_name ?>" >
        <span class="formError"><span id="user_msg"></span></span>
    </span>
  </span>
```

I have a typical validation / errorPlacement code like this:

```
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
  {
    if (element.attr("name") == "user_name" )
        error.insertBefore("#user_msg");
    else
        error.insertAfter(element);
  },
});
```

To submit the form, I have a submit handler that looks like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'add_user.php', 
    data:$('#reg_form').serialize(), 
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.status == "error") {
        if (!response.hasOwnProperty('user_name'))
          $("#user_msg").text("");
        else if (response.user_name.length > 0)
          $("#user_msg").text(response.user_name);
      }
    }
  });
},
```

The response returned is a JSON array, and I can get the error message out just fine. This all works great the first time I submit the form. If I have a duplicate user name, that is displayed properly, or if no user name is input, that is displayed properly too. The problem comes when I submit the form and get a response about a duplicate user name on file. Then if I clear the user_name field and try to submit the form again, the duplicate user name message stays there, and the message saying that a user name is required is displayed also.

To me, it seems as there is a conflict in how these are displayed because the errorPlacement function uses error.insertBefore("#user_msg"), but the return from ajax function uses $("#user_msg").text().  So the insertBefore() does not remove the previous text() values, but I haven't found any other way to display the text from errorPlacement. Can we just get the text value from the error object?  If so, how?  Or is there a better way to make both of these work more in the same way?

Comment: Show the rest of your code.  How/where are you calling `.validate()` for example?

Comment: Chances are you should be using the `remote` functionality of the validate plugin.  That lets you associate an AJAX call with the username, instead of submitting the whole form.

Comment: Validate is called like this:

Comment: @abbaroo, Please **edit** your OP to show the complete `.validate()` code, the HTML for the `form`, and any other event handlers that affect the validate function.  Please make a _complete and concise_ example.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what is your problem exactly.

If you have problem in displaying error like this when an error occurred and you fixed it error will still remain, it is because you did not empty error placement at al.
solution is here before you send new request make your error placement empty.

you can use jquery Dialog for displaying errors in alternative method.

Comment: After looking at it a bit, I see why this is happening. When I enter a character in that field, it goes to the validation routine, but that error text from checking the duplicate user is still there. So I need to clean that out when a key is pressed in that field.

Answer (score 0):

> **Quote:** "Can we just get the text value from the error object? If so, how?"

You can get the text from the `error` object by the following:

```
error.text()
```

Depending on how you use it, you may need to format it like this:

```
$(error).text()
```

Comment: I changed it to use error.text(), which helped fix that problem, but now it causes another. Now the length validation continues to say that the length of the field is too short, even after increasing past the minimum of 5 characters. Oh, it's so fun...

Comment: @abbaroo, please respond to my comments on your OP so I can try to help you better.  Do so by editing your OP.  Thanks.